# Auto resize image depending on screen size (html and css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page written in html and css. Let's suppose my html is composed of just some simple , something like:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
     <title>testpage</title>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    header
  </div>

<div id="central_body">
     <div class="image_area">
          <img id = "image_to_resize" src= "images/image_to_resize.jpg" alt = "">
     </div>
     <div class = "nav">
          nav
     </div>
</div>

<div id="page_footer">
     footer
</div>
</body>
```

As you can see, there is a div that contains an image. The image can be bigger than the screen. I would like to fit all the content to the screen size to make no scroll bars appear; when fitting the content I would like to rescale the image but keeping its original aspect ratio. I want to keep the img tag in the html code. How could I do? I can use html, css and javascript.

Comment: Just set width of the image to be `100vw`, which means it will be 100% as wide as the viewport that is displaying it. The height will automatically adjust to keep the aspect ratio correct.

Comment: *As you can see*, no image, no CSS, no attempt in your example

Comment: Or set the max width if you would like to keep the original width if it is less than the screen width

Comment: Simple CSS: img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css property :

```
.image_area img{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: block; /* remove extra space below image */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the view port to control the page dimensions and scaling.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and use percentages `%` for your div and image width. Set width:100% instead of `px`

if you want the image container to take up the entire viewport, set the div `central_body` height: 100vh;

Answer (score 0):

Definitely your solution is viewport. The general convention for how to use it is, as listed above:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```